# Avoid a pyramid while writing a function in commands.js

Tags: cypress

How can I avoid a pyramid when doing something like this example?

```
Cypress.Commands.add("test", () => {
    
// first request
    cy.request("POST", url1)
        .its("body")
        .then((response) => {
            let userId = response.user._id

            // second request
            cy.request("POST", url2)
                .its("body")
                .then((response) => {
                    let adminAuth = response.accessToken

                    // third request
                    cy.request({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: url
                        headers: { "x-access-token": adminAuth },
                        body: { user: userId }
```

I feel like nesting like this , inside the then(), is quite inneficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Alapan's answer won't work as you can't get a cypress variable value in the same continuation where it was defined. A variable has just not been calculated at this moment (it's not synchronous).
So you can go this way:

```js
// first request
cy.request("POST", url1)
  .its("body")
  .then((response) => {
    cy.wrap(response.user._id).as('userId')
  })

// second request
cy.request("POST", url2)
  .its("body")
  .then((response) => {
    cy.wrap(response.accessToken).as('adminAuth')
  })

// accessing the variables inside a then block to let Cypress to compute them
cy.then(function() {
// third request
  cy.request({
    method: "POST",
    url: url,
    headers: {
      "x-access-token": this.adminAuth
    },
    body: {
      user: this.userId
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Even if this works I'd really like to understand why and how it does.
Why we wrap our request inside an `cy.wrap('').then(fnction() {})`? Why it does not work without that wrapper? Because even if this way we avoid the nesting from the other request we are still coupled to this new introduced wrapper.
And why we pass an empty string as the only argument for `wrap()`? What are we trying to accomplish with that?
I'd really appreciate if somebody could explain that please.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `cy.wrap("")` is used here to start a new Cypress chain. I used it as Cypress docs does not say `then` can be started directly from `cy`. However, it works well and I use it all the time. I've updated the answer and removed the `wrap("")` call.

Comment: As for the additional nesting level, this is required by the asynchronous computation model of Cypress chains. It does not execute the command when it is first encountered, but simply adds it to the queue for later execution. So in order to 'synchronize' the results, we have to access the `adminAuth` and other variables inside a Cypress chain. We cannot access it directly in the root context of a test as it will not yet be computed at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can alias to save the value and then access it using `this.`. Something like:

```js
// first request
cy.request("POST", url1)
  .its("body")
  .then((response) => {
    cy.wrap(response.user._id).as('userId')
  })

// second request
cy.request("POST", url2)
  .its("body")
  .then((response) => {
    cy.wrap(response.accessToken).as('adminAuth')
  })

// third request
cy.request({
  method: "POST",
  url: url,
  headers: {
    "x-access-token": this.adminAuth
  },
  body: {
    user: this.userId
  }
})
```